# Spring data and @EntityGraph on composite primary key

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I have this code :

```
@Table(name = "contact_supplier_function")
@Entity
public class ContactSupplierFunctionEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3969992836064953905L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ContactSupplierFunctionEntityPk contactSupplierFunctionId;

    public ContactSupplierFunctionEntityPk getContactSupplierFunctionId() {
        return contactSupplierFunctionId;
    }

    public void setContactSupplierFunctionId(ContactSupplierFunctionEntityPk contactSupplierFunctionId) {
        this.contactSupplierFunctionId = contactSupplierFunctionId;
    }
}
@Embeddable
public class ContactSupplierFunctionEntityPk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1343896399377494969L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id ", nullable = false)
    private SupplierEntity supplier;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "function_id", nullable = false)
    private FunctionEntity function;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", nullable = false)
    private ContactEntity contact;

    public SupplierEntity getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(SupplierEntity supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public FunctionEntity getFunction() {
        return function;
    }

    public void setFunction(FunctionEntity function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public ContactEntity getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(ContactEntity contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface ContactSupplierFunctionDAO extends CrudRepository<ContactSupplierFunctionEntity, ContactSupplierFunctionEntityPk> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "contactSupplierFunctionId.function" })
    List<ContactSupplierFunctionEntity> findByContactSupplierFunctionIdContactIdAndContactSupplierFunctionIdSupplierIdIn(
            Long contactId, List<Long> supplierIds);
}
```

I would like to load data of my composite primary key with `@EntityGraph` in my repository because I don't want to put it into `Fetch.EAGER`.

But I have this error:

> threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Attribute [contactSupplierFunctionId] is not of managed type; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute [contactSupplierFunctionId] is not of managed type] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute [contactSupplierFunctionId] is not of managed type

Is it possible to make that with `@EntityGraph`?

Do you have another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a solution?